# Ergoemacs cuts selected region when I try to change buffer

Tags: key-bindings, ergoemacs

When I command eval-region to a highlighted area, I would like to quickly change to another buffer with `C-x b` to see the result. However, the first part of this key combination cuts the selected code, even when another shortcut `M-x` does the same thing. Is there a way to disable the keybinding for `C-x` wihtout losing the associated functionality of `C-x b`?

Answer (score 1):

Ergoemacs binds `C-x` to `kill-region` by default.  You can free `C-x` and `C-c` by evaluating:

```
(setq ergoemacs-handle-ctl-c-or-ctl-x 'only-C-c-and-C-x)
```

Alternatively, you could tweak `ergoemacs-ctl-c-or-ctl-x-delay`.  `C-c` and `C-x` work like the default Emacs keybindings only if you press another key within the specified delay (which is set to 0.2 seconds).

More information can be found here:
http://ergoemacs.github.io/cua-conflict.html

Comment: This works like charm.

Comment: @TommiRimpiläinen Nice!  Please mark this answer as accepted then.  Thanks!

Comment: Please consider accepting this question. It is still on the unanswered list. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have CUA-mode enable so you can do:

> (setq cua-enable-cua-keys nil)

Comment: This is about Ergoemacs, not cua-mode.